# pandas rolling max with groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a problem getting the `rolling` function of Pandas to do what I wish. I want for each frow to calculate the maximum so far within the group. Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3], [1,6], [1,3], [2,2], [2,1]], columns=['id', 'value'])
```

looks like

```
   id  value
0   1      3
1   1      6
2   1      3
3   2      2
4   2      1
```

Now I wish to obtain the following DataFrame:

```
   id  value
0   1      3
1   1      6
2   1      6
3   2      2
4   2      2
```

The problem is that when I do

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(1).max()
```

I get the same DataFrame back. And when I do

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(3).max()
```

I get a DataFrame with Nans. Can someone explain how to properly use `rolling` or some other Pandas function to obtain the DataFrame I want?

Comment: If you wanted something similar in spirit to `rolling` you could use `expanding` like this:  `df.groupby('id').expanding().max()`.  However, doing some quick tests this is slower than the other two answers.  Just FWIW, though it is potentially useful since `expanding` does give you additional options over `cummax` if you would need them (e.g. size of window and such)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you need `cummax()` instead of `.rolling(N).max()`

```
In [29]: df['new'] = df.groupby('id').value.cummax()

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   id  value  new
0   1      3    3
1   1      6    6
2   1      3    6
3   2      2    2
4   2      1    2
```

**Timing** (using brand new Pandas version 0.20.1):

```
In [3]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [4]: df.shape
Out[4]: (50000, 2)

In [5]: %timeit df.groupby('id').value.apply(lambda x: x.cummax())
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit df.groupby('id').value.cummax()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.09 ms per loop
```

**NOTE:** [from Pandas 0.20.0 what's new](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200)

- Improved performance of `groupby().cummin()` and `groupby().cummax()` ([GH15048](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15048), [GH15109](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15109), [GH15561](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15561), [GH15635](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15635))

Answer (score 2):

Using apply will be a tiny bit faster:

```
# Using apply  
df['output'] = df.groupby('id').value.apply(lambda x: x.cummax())
%timeit df['output'] = df.groupby('id').value.apply(lambda x: x.cummax())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.57 ms per loop
```

Other method:

```
df['output'] = df.groupby('id').value.cummax()
%timeit df['output'] = df.groupby('id').value.cummax()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
```

Comment: Time to upgrade to Pandas 0.20.1 ;)